# ¿Cómo saber si un iframe muestra su contenido correctamente?

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, iframe

Tengo un `iframe` en el cual quiero visualizar diferentes url dependiendo de la respuesta que obtenga de la base de datos. Hasta ahora tengo varios flujos, cuando obtengo un error no tengo problemas ya que visualizo una imagen para no tener un `iframe` en blanco, cuando la **url** es correcta y se puede visualizar pues todo funciona a la perfección. Entonces mi problema viene dado a que hay momentos en que obtengo una **url** correcta pero el `iframe` no es capaz de visualizar correctamente la **url**, o lo que es lo mismo que tengo un `iframe` en blanco y automáticamente se me descarga el archivo.

El funcionamiento esta bien pero yo quiero que si el iframe no es capaz de visualizar el archivo pues ocultarlo y mostrar una imagen que me de información de lo que acaba de pasar. He probado capturando el evento **load** del `iframe` y no me ha funcionado pues cuando el `iframe` no es capaz de visualizar el contenido de la **url** nunca se llama al evento **load**. Pero tampoco se llama el evento **error** porque la **url** es correcta solo que el `iframe` no es capaz de visualizarla.

`const iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');`
`iframe.onLoad = function() {`
  `// ocultar el cargando y mostrar el iframe`
`}`

Este evento `onLoad` solo se llama cuando la url es correcta y el contenido se carga, pero cuando la url es correcta y el contenido no es capaz de visualizarse pues no se llama el evento. He buscado otros eventos a los que pudiera subscribirme y no encuentro ninguno que pueda capturar este estado.

¿Cómo pudiera darme cuenta de este estado en que no carga el contenido pero a la vez no hay error?

**Nota**
Estoy desarrollando la aplicación en Angular 11 usando TypeScript.

Comment: Prueba si esto ayuda: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15273042/4326551

Comment: Legna gracias por tu comentario pero este caso no me resuelve, porque mi problema es que todo esta bien pero en dependencia del navegador a veces no es posible visualizar el contenido y por eso nunca puedo capturar el onLoad, necesito saber cuando no se puede visualizar en el navegador.